# Why doesn't the int() function convert a float to integer while in input() function?

Tags: python, integer

Why doesn't the int() function convert a float to integer while in `input()` function?

```py
input_1 = input(f'enter the num: ')

try: 
    a = int(input_1)
    print(f"it is an integer")
except:
    print(f"no an integer")
    

input_1 = 3.532453

try: 
    a = int(input_1)
    print(f"it is an integer")
except:
    print(f"no an integer")
```

Result:

```
enter the num: 3.532453
no an integer
it is an integer
```

Comment: Can you pls explain what you mean?

Comment: So first thing, you're trying to make an app that checks if a number is an integer or a float? Also what version of python are you using.

Comment: @RaedAli   I'm using 3.9.0 version of python

Answer (score -4, accepted):

So you can change a decimal to an int in python. **But not without losing all the data past the decimal point.** *For example if you convert "12.3356" to an int using `int(float("12.3356")` and the result would be 12.*

> An **int** value in python is one without a decimal point for eg: 3.
>
> A **float** value in python is a number with a decimal point for eg:
> 3.141.

So, if you want to check if what a user enters is a number **and conserve everything past the decimal point**, convert the strings to a `float` instead of an `int`:

```
input_1 = input('enter the num: ')

try:
    a = float(input_1)
    print("it is a number")
except ValueError:
    print("not a number")
```

By using `float()` instead of `int()`, you get to keep all the data past the decimal point (if you need it in other parts of your program).

However, if you still want to convert a float to an int (and lose everything past the decimal point), you can do:

*Note that the below is basically extra code for a disadvantage and the above is usually better (in most cases), but if that's what you want well here you go:*

```
input_1 = input('enter the num: ')

try:
    a = int(float(input_1))
    print("it is a number")
except ValueError:
    print("not a number")
```

Comment: `you can't change a decimal to an int in python` - that's wrong. Check my answer here.

Comment: `you can't change a decimal to an int in python` - as `bbbbbbbbb` said: this is wrong, you can cast a decimal to an int (losing the decimal part, of course). The point is that `input_1` is not a decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that the `input_1` value when you request for an input is not a float, is a string

```
input_1 = input(f'enter the num: ')
print(type(input_1)) # ​<class 'str'>
```

So with the cast you are trying to convert a string with value `3.532453` into a integer.

If you cast this string to a float first and then you cast it into a integer, it will work.

```
input_1 = input(f'enter the num: ')
try: 
    a = int(float(input_1))
    print(f"it is an integer") 
except: 
    print(f"no an integer")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` function returns a string (type `str` in python). The `int` function accepts a string as long as this string represents a valid integer (base 10 by default). This means when you pass a string that contains a `.`, `int` will fail because the string is not a valid integer.

```
>>> input_1 = input(f'enter the num: ')
enter the num: 3.532453
>>> print(type(input_1))
<class 'str'>
>>> int(input_1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.532453'
```

On the other hand, when you do `input_1 = 3.532453`, you are creating a variable `input_1` of type `float`. The `int` function accepts float arguments and casts them to integer by stripping the floating point part.

```
>>> input_1 = 3.532453
>>> print(type(input_1))
<class 'float'>
>>> int(input_1)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(int(123.456))`: you can convert a non-integer to `int`

`print(int("123456"))`: you can convert a string representing an integer to `int`

`print(int("123.456"))`: you cannot convert a string representing a non-integer to `int`

I mean, you can, but not by using the `int(...)` operation directly.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly you can convert an integer antered as a string to a float with no problems as follows:

```
input_1 = float(input (f'enter the num: '))
print(input_1)
```

But when you try a similar line of code to convert a float to an integer you get an error as follows:

```
input_1 = int(input (f'enter the num: '))
print(input_1)
```

> enter the num: 44.5

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 input_1 = int(input (f'enter the num: '))
> 2 print(input_1)

For your question, you need to convert the string input into a float first, then convert it into an integer as follows:

```
input_1 = int(float(input (f'enter the num: ')))
print(input_1)
```

> enter the num: 55.23
>
> 55